# Getting stylesheet error after setting subdomain to false in multisite

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have installed a multisite wordpress and had `news.mysite.com` as a secondary website. I want to change the address to `mysite.com/news`. To do so, I changed `wp-config.php` to:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I also changed the `.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Which is what I've found in Network Admin -> Settings -> Network Setup

I created a new site at `/news`. The website is accessible but it doesn't load stylesheets properly. I get the following error: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "<URL>".` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:1`

If I go to the old address: `news.mysite.com` it displays correctly and there is no error in the console.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by flushing the permalinks...how do I do that?

Comment: @PatJ Seems like /wp-admin of this newly created blog is not even accessible.

Comment: Because those are `301` (ie, "permanent") redirections, you might need to clear your browser's cookies.

Comment: @PatJ I've cleared cookies and even followed a tutorial to flush permalinks...I'm lost